# How to add product using REST api?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

How to add product using REST api.

**Getting below error -**

```
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 500, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)  
Service temporary unavailable
```

I tried,

```
 $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'));
```

**For above error Solution**

In admin,

```
 System -> Permissions -> Users -> Rest Role -> Select Admin.
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation at Magento http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

Comment: @ArjenMiedema - Thanks, Now I will go through the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step to Add Product Using REST Api

Step-1:  Admin Configuration

1. Create user Role
   Go to **system >Web services >REST** - Roles:
   Click on **Add Admin Role** and create an Admin Role for REST.
   Role info: Provide the role name example '*Admin*'

Resource Access: Set :All
Role Users: Select and admin user to whom you wish to provide Admin REST role

2. Go to **system >Web services >REST Attributes**:
   Select Admin

Set: Resource Access as "All"

3. Go to **system >Web services >OAUTH Consumers**:

### Click on 'Add New' button, it will create a new Oauth consumer, note down the Consumer Key and Consumer secret.

Step-2 : script for create new product via REST API

create test_api.php file at your host
example: location: http://yourdomain/test_api.php
you have to post below fields in json encode format

```
$productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'Simple Product',
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => 99.95,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
```

see code sample at URL: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html#root

Comment: I got error - Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1.9\magento\test_api.php on line 19

Comment: please check  extension=oauth.so into your php.ini 
if not found then put  extension=oauth.so in php.ini 
if staill not working Installing PHP Extension for Oauth : 1. Download php_oauth.dll file and add it under C:\xampp\php\ext\ 2. add [PHP_OAUTH] extension=php_oauth.dll in php.ini

Comment: I have done above steps again and now that error is not coming. But product is not getting added and getting below error.  [message:protected] => Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)

Comment: If i try to get products using www.abc.com/api/rest/products i getting 404 error. How can i solve this issue? Is necessary oAuth should be installed in server? @Piyush